# SSRS big gap between chart and table beneath

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I use SQL server 2008 R2 Report builder 3.0. There are one chart and one table in my SSRS report. When I preview the report,
there is no gap between the chart and table. However, when I receive the subscription of the report in MHTML format. There is a big gap between the chart and table. Can anyone know how to resolve the issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you need it in MHTML? I have never worked with that format but wondering if switching to EXCEL might fix it

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the report template and output?

Answer (score 0):

Try to take the two tables in a rectangle, they will not moove yet I think.

Comment: I include several report items in  a rectangle. But when I run it, they do not show up.